# C# help to improve code - int to hex

Tags: c#

How to reduce or improve the code?

```
private readonly StringBuilder _buffer = new StringBuilder();

public void WriteD(int i) {
    _buffer.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(BitConverter.GetBytes(i)));
}
```

I need to write into string binary data of some datatypes (int, ushort, string, etc.).
String should look like after conversion "stringToHex" as follows (put int 13 and 10):
0D 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00

Thanks!

Comment: Please update your title based on your problem.. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title btw, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I need to add to the string is binary data, not hex. My code works correctly, but I think he's ugly.

Comment: Need add to string 4 bytes for int, 2 bytes for ushort, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void WriteD(int i) {
    _buffer.Append(i.ToString("X4"));
}
```

Comment: This would result in `000D000A`. It would need `X8`, then reverse the byte pairs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(i));`

Comment: Thanks, but this solution returns:C (11): 0D-00-00-00(30 44 2D 30 30 2D 30 30 2D 30 30) instead C (4): * (0D 00 00 00). That is, returns a character string instead of the binary

Comment: I need to add to the string is binary data, not hex. My code works correctly, but I think he's ugly.